How much does the PhD institution matter for getting a Post Doc position in a top institution
how much does the image and ranking(provided by various institutions) matter irrespective of individual work of an institution where you pursue your PhD in getting a Post Doctorate position in a top institution. How much weight will it hold against one's work as in publications etc
